# Azure Files not shows as storage option

Tags: azure-storage

Has anyone had any luck in getting Azure files to work?
it does not show as an option even though Azure says I have been accepted for preview

Answer (score 1):

Once your accepted for preview, you'll be notified that you can access the File storage preview. You can then create a storage account for accessing File storage.
File storage is currently available only for new storage accounts. After your subscription is granted access to File storage, create a new storage account for use with this guide. [Link](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/storage-dotnet-how-to-use-files/)